# Marking files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am working on a project with a huge number of files in eclipse.  Everynow and again when I am following code around I would really like to be able to temporary mark the 5 or so files that are relevant to the code I am following around.  This would make it easier to jump between the 5 or so files when I am figuring out what is going on.  Any ideas - besides close everything and just open those files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use bookmarks. You can create a bookmark by going to **Edit > Add Bookmark**. Then open the **Bookmarks** view to see a list of your bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remember those file names, you can use shortcut Ctrl + Shift + R (or) Ctrl + Shift + T to open them quickly. You don't need to go to file browser and look for those files.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using bookmarks, you can use a plugin like Mylyn. It automatically keeps track of files you've been in while working on a task. This 'state' can then be cleared and restored later (by switching tasks).

Might be overkill for what you need, though.